# How to Capture Redirection URL of a C++ wget URL command

Tags: c++, url, redirect, wget, steam

I am writing some c++ code that scrapes the URLs to the top 10 Steam games, based on the number of players, and then plan to use those URLs to get images from the games. Overall, the system I am using to take those found URLs and find image links is working except for when a game is either age-restricted or when the game's homepage does not match the standard Steam game layout.

I have a vector of the top 10 game URLs but when a game like GTA V is in the vector, the link will redirect to a new link. I have noticed the new redirected URL contains the string "agecheck" so I could easily write a small if block that skips over any games that redirect to a URL with that string but I am not sure how to capture the redirection URL. I am pulling the links from this URL https://store.steampowered.com/stats/Steam-Game-and-Player-Statistics

An example of my problem is my code finds this URL for GTA V
https://store.steampowered.com/app/271590/Grand_Theft_Auto_V/

but that link redirects to the URL

https://store.steampowered.com/agecheck/app/271590/

Given a string that contains a URL, how do I go about finding the URL that link redirects to? Or how can I avoid the redirection?

The code below is what I have so far, I would want to capture the redirection URL within the collect_images_url function so that I could write an if loop within that function.
I am totally aware this code is not documented at all and not very good to look at but right now I am looking for functionality first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int system(const char *command);
std::vector<std::string> collect_top_ten();
std::string collect_image_url(std::string url);

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> links = collect_top_ten();
  std::string temp;

  for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++)
  {
    temp = collect_image_url(links.at(i));
    std::cout << "\n\nFOUND URL: " << temp << std::endl;
    links.at(i) = temp;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++)
  {
    std::cout << links.at(i) << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}

std::string collect_image_url(std::string url)
{
  std::string command = "wget " + url;
  system((const char*)command.c_str());
  std::ifstream ifs("index.html");
  std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

  std::size_t pos = content.find("strip_screenshot");
  content = content.substr(pos);

  pos = content.find("http");
  content = content.substr(pos);
  
  std::size_t pos2 = content.find(">");
  content = content.substr(0, pos2);

  command = "rm index.html";
  system((const char*)command.c_str());

  return content;
}

std::vector<std::string> collect_top_ten()
{
  std::string url = "https://store.steampowered.com/stats/Steam-Game-and-Player-Statistics";
  std::string command = "wget " + url;
  system((const char*)command.c_str());
  std::ifstream ifs("Steam-Game-and-Player-Statistics");
  std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

  std::size_t pos = content.find("detailStats");
  content = content.substr(pos);
  
  std::vector<std::string> urls;

  std::string temp;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    pos = content.find("href");
    content = content.substr(pos);
    std::size_t pos2 = content.find(">");

    temp = content.substr(0, pos2);
    temp = temp.erase(0, 6);
    temp = temp.substr(0, temp.size()-1);

    urls.push_back(temp);

    content = content.substr(pos2);
  }
 
  command = "rm Steam-Game-and-Player-Statistics";
  system((const char*)command.c_str());

  return urls;
}
```